# Linqpad to query tfs2008...... Codesearching tfs2008 via linqpad is this possible?

Tags: tfs, linqpad

I installed linqpad a while ago and recently I came across some articles on how to use it to query against tfs.  Basic queries like checkins and checkouts and things of that nature.  I have had mostly success with running those queries.  Then I see this website showing that it is possible to query against tfs with linqpad basically giving you the ability to do a codesearch with linqpad.  So I spent a very good amount of time attempting to get this to work.

http://pascallaurin42.blogspot.com/2012/05/tfs-queries-searching-in-all-files-of.html

I must say this guy really has a good handle on utilizing linqpad to query tfs.  What I am running into is when I run this I get the error stating that my version of tfs does not allow team branches......  I am really shooting in the dark on this one as I am no tfs expert, but this would be amazing if I could get this to work for tfs2008.  Anyways any help or ideas on this is greatly appreciated....Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versionControl.QueryRootBranchObjects() method isn't supported against a TFS 2008 server because TFS 2008 doesn't understand the concept of a "first-class" branch which was introduced in TFS 2010.  However, you could still accomplish this by supplying your own list of branches.

For instance, if you replace lines 11-25 in the sample above with this code, it should work:

```
var teamBranches = new String[] { "$/project/Main", "$/project/Dev" };

filePatterns.Dump("File patterns");  
textPatterns.Dump("Text patterns");    

foreach (var teamBranch in teamBranches)   
    foreach (var filePattern in filePatterns)    
        foreach (var item in versionControl.GetItems(teamBranch + "/"     + filePattern, RecursionType.Full).Items)     

SearchInFile(item);
```

Obviously, you will want to replace $/project/main and $/project/dev with the branches you would like to search.

Let me know if you have any questions.

*EDIT*

Because you are using TFS 2008 you will also need to tweak a few other lines.  Instead of including

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client
```

Just include

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
```

And instead of this line:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8088/tfs"));
```

Try this

```
// Note, 2008 servers don't use "/tfs" and I can't remember if they take a Uri
// or a string.
var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://localhost:8080");
```

Comment: So, I tried your solution now I get an error in the SearchInFile function basically stating that I don't have the correct reference for Item....which I believe to be Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.dll.  This is because I don't have tfs 2010 or 2012 any ideas on that one?  PS thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with some more details for the 2008 scenario.  Let me know if you hit anymore build/linking errors.

Comment: Thanks again for your update I still get the error. : The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)  I am blowing up on private void SearchInFile(Item file)

Comment: Hmm, that reference should be found in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll.  Can you make sure you are not missing that using?

Comment: I had those listed as additional references and not additional namespace imports....my fault.  Thank you so much Taylor you are a live saver.

Comment: Again thanks Taylor I wish I could answer some of your questions.....if you ever have questions regarding the google maps api make sure to ask me first.

Comment: Hey Taylor do you know if there is a way to have this actually go against tfs versus the team branch of C:?

Comment: Thanks Taylor for answering this one.  It's hard for me to test against a tfs2008 as I don't have access to a server :(